# Write java program to sum of all integers from a random String

Tags: java

I was asked this question in an interview recently (Java programming que)

- Return the sum of all integers from a random String. Continuous Integers must be considered as one number.
- If the input String does not have any Integers, return 0.
- You may ignore decimals, float, and other non-integer numbers
- @param str : Input String
- - Given the following inputs, we expect the corresponding output:
- "-1a2b3c" => 4        (-1+2+3)
- "123ab!45c" => 168   (123+45)
- "abcdef" => 0        (no Integers in String)
- "0123.4" => 127      (0123+4)
- "dFD$#23+++12@#T1234;/.,10"  => 1279  (23+12+1234+10)

### I was allowed to use any inbuilt functions as well

I wrote this code , however this seems little more complex. Can this code be done any other way?

```
public int convertString(String str){
int num=0, currNo = 0;
Boolean isNegative = false;

for (int i=0 ; i<str.length(); i++){
Char t = str.charAt(i) ;

    if(t == ‘-‘){
       if(isNegative)
            num = num-currNo;
        else
            num = num + currNo;

       isNegative=true;
       currNo=0;
    }
    else if(((t-‘0’) <= 9 && (t-‘0’)>=0)){
        currNo = (currNo*10) + t;
    }
    else {

            if(isNegative)
            num = num-currNo;
        else
            num = num + currNo;

        currNo=0;
        isNegative=false;
    }
}


if(isNegative)
            num = num-currNo;
        else
            num = num + currNo;                         
isNegative=true;

return num;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have put your code through a word processor that changed your single quotes to curly unicode weirdness. Also, your indentation is all screwed up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review and belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(str);
long sum = 0;
while(m.find()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It was really helpful. I had not worked much on regex. Now its time for me to learn it !